# bash - redirecting of stdoutput and stderror does not catch all output

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am writing some testing scripts and want to catch all error output and write it to an error log as well as all regular output and write that to a separate log.  I am using a command of the form

cmd > output.file 2> error.file

The command I am writing test scripts for can cause a segmentation fault.  When the command segfaults, bash still prints out segmentation fault to the terminal.

I want this to not happen or get redirected along with standard error.

Is it possible?  It must be of bash's doing because both output streams are being redirected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
bash -c 'cmd >output.file 2>error.file' >bash_output.file 2>&1
```

Comment: Note that behavior is different between shells.  zsh output put it out to a file at all, and regular 'sh' puts the segmentation fault error message in the stderr for the process that segfaulted, while bash seems to put it out on the stderr stream for the parent shell.  Be very sure you know which shell you're working with because of the apparent non-portability of this idea.

Comment: *zsh *DOESN'T* output it out to a file at all.  Goodness, I need to learn how to type.  :-P

Answer (score 0):

I don't think segfaults are part of your program's output from the shell's point of view. So use

**Expect** for more reliable output

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect